# how to check button state in another view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c

My selBtn1 button has toggle the title with black and white color.It works well.

```
//ViewController.m

if (counter == 0) {
    [selBtn1 setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    counter = 1;
}
else if(counter == 1) {
    [selBtn1 setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    counter = 0;
}
```

**Question is :** How to get the currentTitleColor on another view controller for above button.

Thanks

Comment: Declare button as property and pass the view controller instance where required to access it.

Comment: i tried but not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Delegates or Blocks` to know the state of the button in other class. you try with these meanwhile i'll post the code.

Comment: will you post the code for delegates. I don't know how to start.

Comment: Sorry for the delay.Here i just done a sample for [Button status using protocols ](https://github.com/abhilashreddykallepu/protocol-sample) .You can use this sample. If any doubts ask me.

Answer (score 1):

Your counter variable is, de facto, a Model, so the cleanest way is to share that model (which I guess is a more complex class than a simple counter) between the different ViewControllers;
moreover a statusChange notification should be subscribed by the controllers to refresh the button (or whatever) state.

Answer (score 0):

NSNotification is one way to do it..Search for NSNotification tutorial, there are quite a few. You should really get familiar with them, they are used a lot on iOS and Mac OS X development as they are very, very handy.